# $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n: a_n\le x}b_n$ show that $f(-\infty)=0$ and $f(\infty)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, proof-verification

This is an exercise of K.L. Chung's book.

> Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is an arbitrary enumeration of all rationals,$b_n\ge 0,$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges to a finite number.  Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n: a_n\le x}b_n.$$
>   show that $f(-\infty)\triangleq\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=0$ and $f(\infty)\triangleq\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$.

---

It's intuitive that $f(-\infty)=0$ and $f(\infty)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$, since as $x$ becomes smaller, fewer terms of $\{b_n\}$ are included in the summation, and vice versa.  However, I'm not so sure how to prove it rigorously.  I list what I tried below, and would appreciate it if someone can take a look and point out any flaws or a better proof.

---

Suppose $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=c.$  So $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N$ s.t. $\forall K\ge N$ we have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^K b_n>c-\epsilon.$  Now consider $A\triangleq\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_N\}$, and let $a_{\max}=\max A.$  Then $\forall x>a_{\max}$, $f(x)\ge \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N b_n$, and hence $|f(x)-c|<\epsilon,$ since $f$ is clearly monotonically increasing.  This shows $f(x)\to c$, as $x\to \infty.$

Similarly, let $a_{\min}=\min A.$  Then $\forall x<a_{\min},$ it follows that $f(x)\le \displaystyle \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} b_n<\epsilon$.  Since $f(x)\ge 0$ obviously, this implies that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=0.$

---

Are the arguments above correct?  Are there flaws or better proofs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is quite legit. Nice job!

---

We can give a shorter and intuitively simpler proof if some big theorems are available to you, although thinking that this example appears at the very beginning of K.L.Chung's *A Course in Probability Theory* I guess this is probably not the case.

Anyway here is a solution using the [*dominated convergence theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem): We begin by writing

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \mathbf{1}_{\{a_n \leq x\}},$$

where $\mathbf{1}_{\{a_n \leq x\}}$ is the indicator function of $a_n \leq x$, i.e., it takes value $1$ when $a_n \leq x$ holds and $0$ otherwise. Then by the dominated convergence theorem, we can pass limit inside the sum. So we have

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lim_{x\to\infty} b_n \mathbf{1}_{\{a_n \leq x\}}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n $$

and similarly

$$ \lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lim_{x\to-\infty} b_n \mathbf{1}_{\{a_n \leq x\}}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0
= 0. $$

---

A less transparent but still shorter proof is available once we have the following easy-to-prove lemma at our hands:

> **Lemma.** Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets and $f : A\times B \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Then
>
> $$ \sup_{a\in A}\sup_{b\in B}f(a, b)
> = \sup_{(a,b)\in A\times B}f(a, b)
> = \sup_{b\in B}\sup_{a\in A}f(a, b). $$

Now by the monotonicity,

$$ f(\infty)
= \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \sup_{N\geq 1} \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n \mathbf{1}_{\{a_n \leq x\}}
= \sup_{N\geq 1} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n \mathbf{1}_{\{a_n \leq x\}}
= \sup_{N\geq 1} \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n. $$

Similarly, if we consider $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n - f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \mathbf{1}_{\{a_n > x\}}$, then

$$ g(-\infty)
= \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \sup_{N\geq 1} \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n \mathbf{1}_{\{a_n > x\}}
= \sup_{N\geq 1} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n \mathbf{1}_{\{a_n > x\}}
= \sup_{N\geq 1} \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n $$

and hence $f(-\infty) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation and providing 2 alternative proofs! They're very helpful, and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=c.$  So $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N$ s.t. $\forall K\ge N$ we have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^K b_n>c-\epsilon.$  `(True though, the following argument is for a fixed` $\epsilon>0$ `. It is a bit strange to use the quantifier` $\forall$ `this way.)`
>
> Now consider $A\triangleq\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_N\}$, and let $a_{\max}=\max A.$  Then $\forall x>a_{\max}$, $f(x)\ge \sum_{n=1}^N b_n$ `(by the definition of f)`, and hence $|f(x)-c|<\epsilon$ `(OK,` $c-\epsilon<f(x)<c+\epsilon$ `and the second inequality is from the definition of` $f$ `)`, since $f$ is clearly monotonically increasing `(how is the monotonicity of` $f$ `relevant here?)`.  This shows $f(x)\to c$, as $x\to \infty.$
>
> Similarly, let $a_{\min}=\min A.$  Then $\forall x<a_{\min},$ it follows that `(again by the definition of` $f$ `)` $f(x)\le \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} b_n<\epsilon$.  Since $f(x)\ge 0$ obviously, this implies that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=0.$

---

Are the arguments above correct? `(Yes.)`

Comment: You're right.  Instead of saying "since $f$ is clearly monotonically increasing", I should've said "since clearly $f(x)\le c.$"  Thanks for pointing this out, and other comments!